# X205TA grub error

Tags: grub2, grubrescue, grub-efi

I've installed Ubuntu desktop 16.10 on my Asus x205ta. As disk I used a 64GB micro sd card. The installation didn't return any error but when I try to boot from the micro sd it goes in grub rescue mode with the error "no such device". I've tried to reinstall grub and to change the udid on the fstab file but it doesn't fixed anything. I suppose that grub can't see the sd card. What should I do?

**EDIT**

I found why it didn't work. The x205ta doesn't allow boot from micro SD card slot and my adapter doesn't work with 64GB SD. Is there any way to boot from the sd card without using any external usb for every boot?

Comment: I have that device, and it is... tricky. I am not aware of anyone managing to get it to actually boot from micro SD card, though [someone did manage to put their `/home` partition on one](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254322&page=114&p=13535474#post13535474) I recommend you visit the forum thread about the X205TA (well over 1000 posts now) and try using harryharryharry's script, which has worked for me every time I install.

Comment: Maybe it would boot if you get a good *USB adapter for SD or micro SD cards*. All of them work for storage. Some of them can boot in some computers, others boot in other computers. I have a few such adapters, and none of the works 100%, so you need a bit of luck to get one that works. I think Transcend and Kingston adapters are among the best.

Comment: @sudodus It doesn't work either

Comment: I found why it didn't work. The x205ta doesn't allow boot from micro SD card slot and my adapter doesn't work with 64GB SD. Is there any way to boot from the sd card without using any external usb for every boot?

Comment: @RodSmith it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a separate ~500MB `/boot` partition on the device's main internal storage (or whatever the firmware *does* support). The bulk of the Ubuntu installation can be on anything that the Linux kernel can access, but the boot loader, kernel, and related files must be accessible to the firmware.